# Media player doesn't play recording , when media recording is paused

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

i am working on a app where user can record audio,pause it if api level is above 23.And user can listen to the paused recording.

**But what i found is, user is unable to listen to paused audio. But what i want is user can listen to paused audio**

When recording is stopped it is playable as it is stored in a local path.
I also checked android documentation and many answers on stack overflow like how to play paused audio but i can't find any particular links.

i am sharing my question here. if you have any solution or find any link how to solve  my problem it is highly appreciated.

Please let me know even if i need to share my code. As i didn't find it necessary to share code. because when user stops the recording, it should be playable.

**Below is my code**

```
public class AudioRecordingActivity extends BaseActivity
    implements AppDialog.IYesListener,
    AppDialog.IDiscardRecordingListener, AppDialog.ICancelRecordingListener,
    PlayAudioManager.IVoiceCompleteListener,
    MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.createLogger(AudioRecordingActivity.class);
private TaskDetailsViewModel mViewModel;
private ActivityAudioRecordingBinding mBinding;
private AssignmentIdsModel mAssignmentIdModel;
private long mStartTime = 0;
private long mPauseTime=0;
private MediaRecorder mRecorder;
private File mOutputFile;
public final ObservableField<Integer> mAudioState = new ObservableField<>(0);
private String mAudioPath;
private int mMaxAudioTime;
private int[] amplitudes = new int[100];
private int i = 0;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private PlayAudioManager mAudioManager;
private Runnable mTickExecutor = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tick();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTickExecutor, 1000);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreatingBase(Bundle savedInstanceState, Intent intent) {
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(TaskDetailsViewModel.class);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_audio_recording);
    mAudioManager = new PlayAudioManager();
    mAssignmentIdModel = intent.getParcelableExtra(AppConstants.AppExtras.EXTRA_ASSIGNMENT_MODEL);
    mMaxAudioTime = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(AppConstants.AppExtras.EXTRA_DURATION));
    mAudioPath = MediaUtils.getAudioPath(this, mAssignmentIdModel);
    mBinding.ivBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBinding.rlRecording.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBinding.ivAudioDelete.setOnClickListener(this);
    mBinding.tvSave.setOnClickListener(this);
    setPlayIconClickable(false);
    setSaveButtonClickable(false);
    setCrossIconClickable(false);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.iv_back:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
        case R.id.rl_recording:
            startStopRecording();
            break;
        case R.id.iv_play_audio:
            playStopMediaPlayer();
            break;
        case R.id.iv_audio_delete:
            AppDialog.showDeleteAudioDialog(this, this);
            break;
        case R.id.tv_save:
            saveRecording();
            break;
    }
}

private void saveRecording() {
    mViewModel.saveMediaResponse(mAssignmentIdModel, mAudioPath);
    finish();
}

private void playStopMediaPlayer() {
    if (mAudioManager.isMediaPlayerPlaying()) {
        mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_after_recording_icon);
        setSaveButtonClickable(true);
        setCrossIconClickable(true);
        setPlayIconClickable(true);
        mAudioManager.killMediaPlayer();
        mBinding.rlRecording.setClickable(true);
        mBinding.rippleBackground.stopRippleAnimation();
    } else {
        playRecording();
    }
}

private void startStopRecording() {
    switch (mAudioState.get()) {
        case AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_IDLE_STATE:
            hasAudioPermission();
            break;
        case AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_RECORDING_STATE:
            pauseStopRecording();
            break;
        case AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_PAUSE_STATE:
            resumeRecording();
            break;
        case AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_STOP_STATE:
            AppDialog.showNewRecordingDialog(this, this);
            break;
    }
}

private void hasAudioPermission() {
    if (PermissionUtils.hasPermissions(this, PermissionUtils.RC_REQUEST_PERMISSION_RECORD_AUDIO,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)) {
        startRecording();
    }

}


private void tick() {
    long time = (mStartTime < 0) ? 0 : (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mStartTime);
    int minutes = (int) (time / 60000);
    int seconds = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;
    int milliseconds = (int) (time / 100) % 10;
    mBinding.tvTimer.setText((minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : "00") + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds));
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        amplitudes[i] = mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
        LOGGER.debug("Voice Recorder", "amplitude: " + (amplitudes[i] * 100 / 32767));
        if (i >= amplitudes.length - 1) {
            i = 0;
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}


private void deleteRecording() {
    AppUtils.deleteFile(mAudioPath);
    mAudioState.set(AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_IDLE_STATE);
    setPlayIconClickable(false);
    setCrossIconClickable(false);
    setSaveButtonClickable(false);
    mStartTime = 0;
    mBinding.tvTimer.setText("00:00");
    mBinding.tvStartRecording.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_start_recording));
    mBinding.rlRecording.setClickable(true);
}

private void playRecording() {
    try {
        Uri videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                mOutputFile);
        mAudioManager.playAudio(this, this, videoUri);
        mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon_small);
        setSaveButtonClickable(false);
        setCrossIconClickable(false);
        setPlayIconClickable(true);
        mBinding.rlRecording.setClickable(false);
        mBinding.rippleBackground.startRippleAnimation();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void pauseRecording() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mRecorder.pause();
        mPauseTime=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        mAudioState.set(AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_PAUSE_STATE);
        mBinding.tvStartRecording.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_recording_is_paused));
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTickExecutor);
        whenRecordingIsPausedOrStopped();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private void resumeRecording() {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mRecorder.resume();
        mStartTime = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mPauseTime) + mStartTime;
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTickExecutor, 1000);
        mAudioState.set(AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_RECORDING_STATE);
        mBinding.tvStartRecording.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_recording));
        whenRecordingIsInStartState();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}


private boolean isBuildVersionIsGreaterOrEqualN() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


private void pauseStopRecording() {
    if (isBuildVersionIsGreaterOrEqualN()) {
        pauseRecording();
    } else {
        stopRecording();
    }
}


private void startRecording() {
    whenRecordingIsInStartState();
    mOutputFile = getOutputFile();
    mOutputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(48000);
    mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
    mRecorder.setMaxDuration((mMaxAudioTime * 1000));
    mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mTickExecutor, 1000);
        LOGGER.debug("Voice Recorder", "started recording to " + mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Voice Recorder", "prepare() failed " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void whenRecordingIsInStartState() {
    mAudioState.set(AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_RECORDING_STATE);
    setPlayIconClickable(false);
    setCrossIconClickable(false);
    mBinding.tvStartRecording.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_recording));
    mBinding.ivRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseicon);
    setSaveButtonClickable(false);
}

private void setSaveButtonClickable(boolean isClickable) {
    if (isClickable) {
        mBinding.tvSave.setAlpha(1.0f);
        mBinding.tvSave.setClickable(true);
        mBinding.tvSave.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    } else {
        mBinding.tvSave.setAlpha(0.5f);
        mBinding.tvSave.setClickable(false);
        mBinding.tvSave.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorMediumText));
    }
}

private File getOutputFile() {
    return new File(mAudioPath);
}


protected void stopRecording() {
    mAudioState.set(AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_STOP_STATE);
    mBinding.tvStartRecording.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.txt_recording_is_stopped));
    whenRecordingIsPausedOrStopped();
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mStartTime = 0;
    mPauseTime=0;
    mRecorder = null;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTickExecutor);
}

private void whenRecordingIsPausedOrStopped() {
    setPlayIconClickable(true);
    setCrossIconClickable(true);
    mBinding.ivRecord.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_recording);
    setSaveButtonClickable(true);
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
        if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            AppUtils.showShortSnackBar(mBinding.tvSave, R.string.err_permission_denied);
            return;
        }
    }
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PermissionUtils.RC_REQUEST_PERMISSION_RECORD_AUDIO:
            startRecording();
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void setPlayIconClickable(boolean isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
        mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setClickable(true);
        mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setAlpha(1.0f);
    } else {
        mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setAlpha(0.5f);
        mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setClickable(false);
    }
}

private void setCrossIconClickable(boolean isVisible) {
    if (isVisible) {
        mBinding.ivAudioDelete.setClickable(true);
        mBinding.ivAudioDelete.setAlpha(1.0f);
    } else {
        mBinding.ivAudioDelete.setAlpha(0.5f);
        mBinding.ivAudioDelete.setClickable(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onYesClicked() {
    deleteRecording();
}

@Override
public void onVoiceComplete() {
    mBinding.ivPlayAudio.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_after_recording_icon);
    setCrossIconClickable(true);
    setSaveButtonClickable(true);
    setPlayIconClickable(true);
    mBinding.rlRecording.setClickable(true);
    mBinding.rippleBackground.stopRippleAnimation();
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mAudioState.get() == AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_RECORDING_STATE) {
        mAudioManager.killMediaPlayer();
        finish();
    } else if (mAudioState.get() == AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_STOP_STATE) {
        AppDialog.showCancelRecordingDialog(this, this);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {
    if (i == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
        LOGGER.debug("AUDIOCAPTURE", "Maximum Duration Reached");
        stopRecording();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mAudioManager.isPlaying()) {
        //PlayAudioManager.killMediaPlayer();
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onYesDiscardClicked() {
    startRecording();
}

@Override
public void onDeleteRecording() {
    AppUtils.deleteFile(mAudioPath);
    finish();
}

/**
 * this method will be called when any interrupt happens or home button is pressed
 */
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    if (mRecorder != null && mAudioState.get() == AudioRecordingEnum.AUDIO_RECORDING_STATE) {
        stopRecording();
    }
    if (mAudioManager.isPlaying()) {
        //PlayAudioManager.killMediaPlayer();
    }
    super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
}
```

**Below is Audio Playing class**

```
public class PlayAudioManager {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private IVoiceCompleteListener iVoiceCompleteListener;

public PlayAudioManager() {

}

public void playAudio(IVoiceCompleteListener listener, final Context context, Uri uri) throws Exception {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri);
    }
    iVoiceCompleteListener = listener;
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(
            mp -> killMediaPlayer());
    mediaPlayer.start();
}


public void pauseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

public void playMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}

public void killMediaPlayer() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        try {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            mediaPlayer = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (iVoiceCompleteListener != null) {
        iVoiceCompleteListener.onVoiceComplete();
    }

}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        killMediaPlayer();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean isMediaPlayerPlaying() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public interface IVoiceCompleteListener {
    void onVoiceComplete();
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your code, there can be many reasons for that and also share how You are saving the recording during pause state.

Comment: @theJango , i have shared my code

Comment: @Tarun please make sure the uri points to the recored file

Comment: @Jeeva , Recording is stored when i call mediaRecorder.stop() but when i call mediaRecorder.pause() , it doesn't stored in path. no issue in URI.

Comment: @i still dont get it

Comment: did u fix it @Tarun

Comment: @Jeeva , No....

Comment: @Tarun thats bad

Comment: @Tarun do you have your project in github??

Comment: @Jeeva , Yes. but repository is not public.

Comment: @Tarun     mAudioPath = MediaUtils.getAudioPath(this, mAssignmentIdModel); cant find any method name getAudioPath in android docs??

Comment: @Tarun are you sure there is file once you pause ??

Comment: @Tarun did u check whether if the file exists using file explorer

Comment: @Jeeva , file doesn't exist in file explorer after pause.
getAudioPath() is method is in my utility class.

Comment: public static String getAudioPath(Context context) {
        String subDirectoryPath = "Abc" + File.separator + 123 + File.separator +456;
        String fileName = File.separator + 12 + mp3;
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(subDirectoryPath).getAbsolutePath());
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + fileName);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }

Comment: @Tarun please make sure first the file is created and then try to play.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177021/discussion-between-jeeva-and-tarun).

Answer (score 0):

MediaRecorder when start recording is open fileoutputstream under the hood (i think) and while this fileoutputstream is not closed (while recorder.release() is not called) you can't read data from this file.
To achieve playing audio while in pause state you should use AudioRecorder.
Sample implementation can be checked here: [AudioRecorder library](https://github.com/Dimowner/AudioRecorder/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/dimowner/audiorecorder/audio/recorder/WavRecorder.java)

Code from source should be edited in this way:

```
private void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(recordFile, true);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Timber.e(e);
        fos = null;
    }
    ...
}
```

So, when recording will resume you will write data to existing file. When recording paused, audioRecorder should be stopped and released.
Appling this change and another small changes to source code help to fit my requirements.